# How to add custom field in magento admin side for add category?

Tags: magento, zend-framework, magento-1.7

I'm new to **magento** and i'm using **magento** 1.7.0.2 . In this admin side category add file, i want to add one check box extra, but i don't know the add category file name and folder structure path. So can any one guide me and where the files are located , how to add check box on that.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add another checkbox in the form of an attribute. You have to build a small module with an installation script. See this [tutorial](http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/)